# Pointer to pointer member Struct

Tags: c

Its a part of code that i working on. When i try to assign `Diagcb.end` to `ptr2` it returned an error.

I tried to write it as:

```
ptr2 = &Diagcb.end;
ptr2 = &diagcb->end;
```

but the same error is returned.

```
typedef struct reportType {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int* ptr;
} reportType;

typedef struct cb {
    reportType* start;
    reportType* end;
    reportType arr[10];
}cb;
int fun (reportType* report);
main()
{
    cb Diagcb;
    reportType report;
    report.a = 0;
    report.b = 1;
    report.c = 2;
    report.ptr = NULL;
    reportType* ptr2;
    ptr2 = cb.end;
}
```

Comment: Did you want a pointer to the pointer, i.e. a `reportType**`? If you just want to copy the value to another `reportType*` then `Diagcb.end` should work, but in this example you haven't initialised that value first.

Comment: `ptr2 = Diagcb.end2;` It is already a pointer, you dont need its address.[note: the choice of variable names and case is *very*  confusing]

Comment: @wildplasser
Yes u r right; its work. I know the names is garbage; i just to test if it will work before i will start in programming. Thanks alot

Comment: I am a bit confused about the difference between: reportType* ptr2; ptr2 = Diagcb.end; and reportType** ptr2; ptr2 = &Diagcb.end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it as `ptr2 = Diagcb.end`. Because `Diagcd.end` is already a pointer, you don't need to use `&` to get the address.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the difference between:
    reportType* ptr2;
    ptr2 = Diagcb.end;  
and
    reportType** ptr2;
    ptr2 = &Diagcb.end;

Comment: The first one is a pointer to the reportType, the second one is a pointer to the pointer to the reportType. If you want to access the value `a` via a pointer `ptr`, you can use `ptr->a`. Instead via a pointer to the pointer `pptr`, you should write it as `(*pptr)->a`, with `*` op to get the pointer first.